# How to select new element everytime

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-grid

I have iterated dropdown

```
Select Exptypedropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='InputSection']/table[@name='RTExpense']//tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/select[@name='ExpenseType']")));
        List<WebElement> listofExpenses = Exptypedropdown.getOptions();
        System.out.println("number of expenses: " + listofExpenses.size());

        for (int j = 1; j < listofExpenses.size(); j++) {
            AddnewExp.click();
            Exptypedropdown.selectByIndex(j)
```

---

Now using `AddnewExp` I am adding new expense everytime and want next option to be selected from dropdown.
but as "**J**" is assigned to first element, i can able to select new option but it's happening only in 1st expenses, not in the new one which i have added. I can see everytime I am clicking on `AddnewExp` new `<tr>` is getting created, but unable to code this. Can someone help me?

Comment: First click AddnewExp then load the elements to Exptypedropdown list then comes your for loop. That is if your are trying to click the expense you just added.

Comment: I would suggest you share minimal reproducible code to check what is the issue that you are facing. In my guess you are adding a new row to the table and then you want to select some option in that new row. If that's the case then you would need to locate the new row after clicking on the AddNewExp control